# Merge Tags: ios and mobilesdkios

Tags: discussion, tag-merge

I think these 2wo can be merged

What do you think?

[ios](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios)

[salesforcemobilesdk-ios](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salesforcemobilesdk-ios)

Answer (score 6):

Strictly speaking, you can develop a Salesforce mobile client app on iOS without using the Mobile SDK, so they aren't strictly synonyms. That's not to say that all questions are correctly tagged, though...

Answer (score 2):

I second what Patt mentioned. You could always get questions related to

```
A) Using Mobile SDK for iOS 
B) Using Salesforce1 on iOS which has no relation to Mobile SDK 
C) Running Mobile VF pages on iOS (iPhone, iPad), which again may/ may not have relation to Mobile SDK 
E) Admin related questions on iOS which again may not have any relation to Mobile SDK
```